# How can I ensure that my CSS content fits perfectly within the web browser window?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, iframe

How can I ensure that my CSS content fits perfectly within the web browser window?

I'm facing an issue where the content, with dimensions of Width 1917.00 x Height 850.00, extends beyond the boundaries of my laptop's Chrome browser window, requiring me to scroll to view it. Interestingly, on another laptop of the same model and browser, the content fits perfectly without the need for scrolling.

To mitigate this, I've observed that decreasing the zoom level to 75% on my laptop's browser resolves the issue, allowing the content to fit snugly within the window without requiring a scrollbar.

Now, my question is: where in the CSS can I adjust the size to 75% universally, ensuring that the content fits perfectly within the browser window on every laptop model? My primary objective is to display the content fully without necessitating the use of a scrollbar.

I also do not want the button text size view to get smaller.

Here is my CSS CODE:

```
body {
  background-color: #fefff4;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#fefff4, #fefff4);
  margin: 0;
}

#bannerPx {
  padding: 0;
}

/* Banner Wrapper */
#banner {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
  align-items: center;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #4fb3ff;
}

/* Banner Text */
#banner_text {
  text-align: center;
  font: bold 36px Century Gothic;
  color: #000000;
  z-index: 11;
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-right: 60px;
}

#banner_text2 {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#bannerimg {
  height: 100%;
}

#bannerIncludePx {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#content {
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 1917px; 
  height: 870px;
}

#content iframe {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 1917px;
  height: 870px;
  z-index: 300;
  background-color: #fefff4;
}

#console {
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#console iframe {
  width: 100;%
  z-index: 200;
}

nav {
  margin: 0px 0px auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

ul li img {
  margin-left: -20px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#ci_wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1917px;
  padding: 8px;
}

#menu,
#menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #4fb3ff;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #777;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

#menu:before,
#menu:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

#menu:after {
    clear: both;
}

#menu {
    zoom:1;
}

#menu li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}


#menu a {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    color: #212121;
    text-transform: none;
    font: bold 15px Segoe UI;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#menu li:hover > a {
    color: #000000;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#4fb3ff, #4fb3ff);
}

#menu li:hover > a svg {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

*html #menu li a:hover { /* IE6 only */
    color: #b6c3d4;
}

#menu ul {
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    _margin: 0; /*IE6 only*/
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 41px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;    
    background: #FFFFFF;   
    background: linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #FFFFFF);
    box-shadow: 20px 20px 50px grey;   
    border-radius: 0px;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

#menu li:hover > ul {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    margin: 0;
}

#menu ul ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    _margin: 0; /*IE6 only*/
    box-shadow: -1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3);      
}

#menu ul li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    border: 0;
    _line-height: 0; /*IE6 only*/
    box-shadow: 0 0px 0 #111, 0 0px 0 #666;
}

#menu ul li:last-child {   
    box-shadow: none;    
}

#menu ul a {    
    padding: 10px 25px;
    _height: 10px; /*IE6 only*/
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: none;
    text-transform: none;
}

#menu ul a:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#0095ff, #0095ff);
    color : #000000;
    font-size :14.5px;
}
#menu li a:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#0095ff, #0095ff);
    color : #000000;
}

#menu ul li:first-child > a {
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0 0;
}

#menu ul li:first-child > a:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    top: -6px;
    border-left: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #FFFFFF;
}

#menu ul ul li:first-child a:after {
    left: -6px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    border-left: 0; 
    border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
    border-top: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid #FFFFFF;
}

#menu ul li:first-child a:hover:after {
}

#menu ul ul li:first-child a:hover:after {
    border-right-color: #424242; 
    border-bottom-color: transparent;   
}

#menu ul li:last-child > a {
    border-radius: 0 0 0px 0px;
}

/* Mobile */
#menu-trigger {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    #menu-wrap {
        position: relative;
    }

    #menu-wrap * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    #menu-trigger {
        display: block;
        height: 40px;
        line-height: 40px;
        cursor: pointer;        
        padding: 0 0 0 35px;
        border: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
        color: #9E9E9E;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: #fff;
        background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBOR...) no-repeat 10px center, linear-gradient(#BDBDBD, #111);
        border-radius: 6px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #777, 0 1px 0 #666 inset;
    }

    #menu {
        margin: 0; padding: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 40px;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
        display: none;
        box-shadow: none;       
    }

    #menu:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        left: 25px;
        top: -8px;
        border-left: 8px solid transparent;
        border-right: 8px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 8px solid #BDBDBD;
    }   

    #menu ul {
        position: static;
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
        margin: 0;
        background: none;
        box-shadow: none;               
    }

    #menu ul ul {
        margin: 0 0 0 20px !important;
        box-shadow: none;       
    }

    #menu li {
        position: static;
        display: block;
        float: none;
        border: 0;
        margin: 5px;
        box-shadow: none;           
    }

    #menu ul li{
        margin-left: 20px;
        box-shadow: none;       
    }

    #menu a{
        display: block;
        float: none;
        padding: 0;
        color: #212121;
    }

    #menu a:hover{
        color: #9E9E9E;
    }   

    #menu ul a{
        padding: 0;
        width: auto;        
    }

    #menu ul a:hover{
        background: none;   
    }

    #menu ul li:first-child a:after,
    #menu ul ul li:first-child a:after {
        border: 0;
    }    

}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    #menu {
        display: block !important;
    }
}   

/* iPad */
.no-transition {
    transition: none;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    display: none;          
}

#menu li:hover > .no-transition {
    display: block;
    background-color: #b6c3d4;
}
svg {
    transition: transform 0.5s ease;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#menu li a img {
    float: left;
}
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!-- @noSnoop -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="icon" href="img/emslogo.ico" type="image/icon type">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <!--script type="text/javascript">
    window.history.forward();
    function noBack() {
        window.history.forward();
    }
  </script--> 
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="ci_wrapper">
   
   <nav id="menu-wrap">
    <ul id="menu">
      <li id="banner">
          <!--img id="bannerimg" src="../images/framework/banner.png"/-->
          <div id="banner_text">AAAA</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href=""><img src="../images/framework/homeIcon.png"/> Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="dropdown" href="#">C
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="11" height="7" viewBox="0 0 11 7">
          <polygon points="0.06 1.19 5.5 6.53 10.94 1.19 10.24 0.47 5.5 5.13 0.76 0.47 0.06 1.19" fill="black">
        </a>

        <ul class="sub-dropdown">
          <li>
              <a href="" target="contentFrame">Overview</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">C</a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="" target="contentFrame">Main</a>
              </li> 
              <li>
                <a href="" target="contentFrame">C1</a>
              </li> 
              <li>
                <a href="" target="contentFrame">C2</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="" target="contentFrame">C3</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="" target="contentFrame">CT</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="" target="contentFrame">l</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="" target="contentFrame">Control</a>
              </li> 
                        
            </ul>
          </li>
   
          <li>
            <a href="#">Level</a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="" target="contentFrame"> 1</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="" target="contentFrame"> 2</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href=" target="contentFrame"> 3</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="" target="contentFrame">D</a>
          </li> 
          <li>
            <a href="" target="contentFrame">Status</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="" target="contentFrame">Eny </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="" target="contentFrame">S</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="" target="contentFrame">k</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
 
<!-- A-->         
      <li>
        
        <a class="dropdown" href="#">A
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="11" height="7" viewBox="0 0 11 7">
          <polygon points="0.06 1.19 5.5 6.53 10.94 1.19 10.24 0.47 5.5 5.13 0.76 0.47 0.06 1.19" fill="black">
        </a>

        <ul class="sub-dropdown">
          <li>
              <a href="" target="contentFrame">O</a>
          </li>
          
          <li>
              <a href="" target="contentFrame">1</a>
          </li>
          
          <li>
              <a href="" target="contentFrame">2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        
      </li>
 <!-- A --> 
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          H
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="11" height="7" viewBox="0 0 11 7">
          <polygon points="0.06 1.19 5.5 6.53 10.94 1.19 10.24 0.47 5.5 5.13 0.76 0.47 0.06 1.19" fill="black">
        </a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <!--a href="">Hi</a-->
              <a href="" target="contentFrame">Hi</a>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href="#">C</a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="" target="contentFrame">C1</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="" target="contentFrame">C2</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="" target="contentFrame">C3</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="" target="contentFrame">G</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a href="" target="contentFrame">P</a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a href="" target="contentFrame">P</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">C</a>
              <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="" target="contentFrame">C</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="" target="contentFrame">C</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="" target="contentFrame">C</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="" target="contentFrame">C</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="" target="contentFrame">gy</a>
            </li>
               
          </ul>

  
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          A
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="11" height="7" viewBox="0 0 11 7">
          <polygon points="0.06 1.19 5.5 6.53 10.94 1.19 10.24 0.47 5.5 5.13 0.76 0.47 0.06 1.19" fill="black">
          
        </a>
          <ul>
           
            <li>
              <a href="" target="contentFrame">Current</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="" target="contentFrame">Database</a>
            </li>
            
          </ul>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          Re
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="11" height="7" viewBox="0 0 11 7">
          <polygon points="0.06 1.19 5.5 6.53 10.94 1.19 10.24 0.47 5.5 5.13 0.76 0.47 0.06 1.19" fill="black">
          
        </a>
          <ul>
           
            <li>
              <a href="" target="contentFrame">D</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="" target="contentFrame">Al</a>
            </li>
            
          </ul>
      </li>
       
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          Users
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="11" height="7" viewBox="0 0 11 7">
          <polygon points="0.06 1.19 5.5 6.53 10.94 1.19 10.24 0.47 5.5 5.13 0.76 0.47 0.06 1.19" fill="black">
          
        </a>
          <ul>
           
            <li>
              <a href="" target="contentFrame">User</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="" target="contentFrame">Activities</a>
            </li>
            
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="" target="contentFrame">Help</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/logout" target="_top">
          <img src="../images/framework/iconLogoff.png"/>Logoff</a>
      </li>
            
    </ul>
    </nav>
      <div id="content">
        <iframe src="" name="contentFrame" frameborder="0"/>
      </div>
      </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/menu.js"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have only shared your CSS, not your HTML. We cannot possibly answer this effectively unless you edit your qeustion to include more detail.

Comment: I just shared my HTML as well.

Comment: Is your issue with the `<nav>` panel, or with `<div id="content">`? Are you trying to make the size of the `iframe` match the size of the browser window? What is being loaded into the `iframe`? You have not included your javascript which does this ...

Comment: I think the issue is <div id="content"> I tried to changed it into like this

#content iframe {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
  z-index: 300;
  background-color: #fefff4;
}

but it still has the problem

Comment: What is the content you are putting **into** the `iframe`? You have not shared that.

Answer (score 1):

> Where in the CSS can I adjust the size to 75% universally

Try this in your HTML:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.75">
```

> ... ensuring that the content fits perfectly within the browser window
> on every laptop model?

Simply choosing an arbitrary `initial-scale` value cannot guarantee this. Laptops and devices come in all shapes and sizes. Even different browsers have different viewport sizes depending on their toolbar configurations and so on. What about phones and tablets? If your question contained more detail about exactly what you are trying to fit onto the screen, we could perhaps provide more direction here ...

Answer (score 1):

It might not be possible to do with pure CSS. You could use the JS to detect the zoom level of the browser first, and then build the style.

```
document.body.style.zoom = 0.75;
```

btw. this JS works on Chrome but may not work on Firefox.

Answer (score -1):

In your HTML code, add a `meta` tag to your `header`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

This should let the browser know how to scale your page based on the device width.

Comment: I already have that HTML code in my header

Comment: I just shared my HTML as well.

Comment: Did you try `initial-scale=0.75`?

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

To ensure your CSS content fits perfectly within the browser window without scrolling, you can use the vw unit. Apply the following CSS rule to the desired elements:

```
body {
  font-size: 75vw;
}
 button{
font-size: 75px;
}
```

Comment: I tried to put it but its still happing I cannot even see the full content and all of them were cut off. Moreover I am still  seeing scroll bar.

Comment: I just shared my HTML as well.

Comment: wow  i think it could help you!